# jquery - count similar data fields/class name in html form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the count of data-fields in HTML form using JavaScript or jQuery

```
<input data-table="assessment_rating" data-field="x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE" 
name="x1_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE" id="x1_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE" 
placeholder="Performance Measure" 
value="" class="form-control" type="text">
```

I have 10 input fields with same name `data-field = "x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE".`

I want to get the count dynamically using jQuery or JavaScript.

I used below code

```
var x = $('#ewTableHeaderCell .x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE').length;
alert (x);
```

I am not getting with the above script...
please help me out.

Comment: got the solution...Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use another selector: look at the example.

```js
//look
var x = $('input[data-field="x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE"]').length;
alert (x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input data-table="assessment_rating" data-field="x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE" 
name="x1_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE" id="x1_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE" 
placeholder="Performance Measure" 
value="" class="form-control" type="text">
```

> Of course since your example didn't include the original `#ewTableHeaderCell` table header cell, I've omitted it out of my snippet. But you get the idea. in your case it is:

```
var x = $('#ewTableHeaderCell input[data-field="x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE"]').length;
```

Since [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) uses [`css selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) under the hood, click the link to learn more.

Comment: Your selector will select every input that has `data-field` no matter where it's placed (I mean in parent container).

Comment: @Justinas, I generalized it, because of lacking HTML in the OP's question and commented it in my answer.

Comment: if i have select in place of input?how do i replace the code?

Comment: replace `input` with `select`. Read the documentation through the provided link. It is really useful. You should get to know CSS selectors.

Comment: is this correct  $('select[data-field="x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE"]').length;?

Comment: Should do the trick!

Answer (score 4):

Since `x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE` is not a class, you can't use class selector `.`

Select it using attribute selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('#ewTableHeaderCell [data-field="x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE"]').length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="ewTableHeaderCell">
<input data-table="assessment_rating" data-field="x_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE" 
name="x1_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE" id="x1_PERFORMANCE_MEASURE" 
placeholder="Performance Measure" 
value="" class="form-control" type="text">
</span>
```