# Count data attributes with similar prefix in html with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The closest any answer comes to my problem are the following two.

[jquery-count-similar-data-fields-class-name-in-html-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605241/jquery-count-similar-data-fields-class-name-in-html-form)

[jquery-count-elements-with-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030691/jquery-count-elements-with-attribute)

I want to count the total number of data attribute with similar prefix.
here are the example of what i want to achieve.

```
<input type="date" data-input-type="date" />

<input type="email" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-type="email" />

<input type="text" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-url="report" data-input-table="sale" />
```

i want to count all the attributes with data-input. I know i can count each attributes separately but i do not know which attributes appear in each page but i am sure that each page has data-input attribute. I can make a count of each attribute separately for example

```
$('[data-input-url]').length
```

but this method would make me write 100 of line just for one purpose

what i want to find is the total count of data attributes with data-input as a prefix in the whole document because i want a function to start when the count is greater than certain number and another function if count is less than certain number in every page. I tried

```
$('[data-input-*]').length;
$('[data-input*]').length;
```

but none of them worked. Could anybody help?

Comment: Please clarify exactly what count you need. Currently this can be interpreted different ways. Count of elements that have any `data-input`, count of ones with a specific one or count of all such attributes

Comment: what i want to find is the total count of data attributes with data-input as a prefix in the whole document. made an edit in the document

Comment: [edit] the question then with a concise explanation. Also why would you ever need this?

Comment: i want a function to start when the count is greater than certain number and another function if count is less than certain number in every page. i edited the document as much concisely as i could to make everybody understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using XPath**

```js
var attrCount = document.evaluate("count(//@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-input-')])", document)

console.log(attrCount.numberValue)
```

```html
<input type="date" data-input-type="date" />

<input type="email" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-type="email" />

<input type="text" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-url="report" data-input-table="sale" />
```

**Using `filter()` and `attributes` property**

```js
var attrCount = 0

$(':input').each(function() { // use * if not :input specific
  attrCount += Array.from(this.attributes).filter(a => a.nodeName.startsWith('data-input-')).length
})

console.log(attrCount)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" data-input-type="date" />

<input type="email" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-type="email" />

<input type="text" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-url="report" data-input-table="sale" />
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are trying count number of attributes in each element, not number of elements...

Answer (score 0):

There is no partial attribute name selector, so one method I could think of is to have a list of possible attribute names:

```js
const list = "[data-input-" + ["type", "length", "min-length", "max-length", "url", "table"].join("],[data-input-") + "]";

const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(list);

for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
  let count = 0;
  for(data in nodes[i].dataset)
  {
    if (!data.indexOf("input")) //name starts with "input"?
      count++;
  }
  console.log(count, nodes[i]);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" data-inputnot-type="date"/>
<input type="date" data-notinput-type="date"/>

<input type="date" data-input-type="date" />

<input type="email" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-type="email" />

<input type="text" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-url="report" data-input-table="sale" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is below:

```js
// using Arrow function syntax to declare a function, passing in a
// default-value for the 'haystack' argument;
// needle:   String, a value by which the collection of attributes
//           is filtered,
// haystack: String, a selector for the element to search within:
const attributeCount = (needle, haystack = 'body') => {

  // here we use document.querySelectorAll(), passing the
  // haystack selector into the function via a template-literal,
  // which allows variables to interpolated in place; the
  // iterable NodeList returned by document.querySelectorAll()
  // is converted to an Array using the Array-literal along with
  // the spread syntax; this allows us to use Array methods
  // on the Array of Nodes:
  let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(`${haystack} *`)],
    // this is a collection of all Attributes present on all
    // elements returned previously, using Array.prototype.map():
    allAttributes = elements.map(
      // here we use an Arrow function to pass the current
      // element-node of the Array of element-nodes we're
      // iterating over into the function:
      (el) => {
        // here we convert the el.attributes NamedNodeMap
        // into an Array, again using the Array-literal and
        // spread syntax; we then iterate over those Attributes
        // using Array.prototype.map():
        let attrs = [...el.attributes].map(
          // another Arrow function, passing in the
          // current key-value Object to the function body:
          (keyVal) => {
            // we use a destructuring assignment to
            // retrieve the nodeName and the nodeValue
            // from the property-values of the same name
            // from the keyVal Object:
            let {
              nodeName,
              nodeValue
            } = keyVal;
            // here we return an Object comprised of the following
            // values:
            return {
              attributeName: nodeName,
              attributeValue: nodeValue
            }
          });
        // and here we return the following Object,
        // with the 'node' property of the Object being the
        // current element-node (in case that might be required
        // in a future context), and an Array of the attributes:
        return {
          'node': el,
          'attributes': attrs,
        }
      }
    ),
    
    // here we use Array.prototype.reduce() to reduce the Array
    // of element-nodes and their attributes to a different format:
    attributeCounts = allAttributes.reduce(
      (acc, curr) => {
        // we create an Array of all the attribute names held in the
        // current Object's attributes Array:
        let keys = curr.attributes.map((a) => a.attributeName);
        // we iterate over those attribute-names using
        // Array.prototype.forEach(), passing the 'key' variable
        // in via the Arrow function syntax:
        keys.forEach(
          (key) => {
            // if there is no key on the accumulator Object
            // matching the current attribute-name:
            if (!acc[key]) {
              // we initialise that Object-property and set
              // its value to 1:
              acc[key] = 1;
            } else {
              // otherwise, if that key does exist we increment
              // its count by one:
              acc[key]++;
            }
          });
          
        // we return the accumulator for the next iteration:  
        return acc;
      // here is the default accumulator initialised for the
      // function:
      }, {}),
    // to rerieve the filtered attribute contents, we use
    // Object.entries() to break down the attributeCounts
    // Object into a two-dimensional Array containing multiple
    // sub-arrays, each of which is a key-value pair of the
    // property-name and property-value of the attributeCounts
    // Object; we then use use Array.prototype.filter() to filter
    // that Array of key-value pairs:
    filteredAttributeCount = Object.entries(attributeCounts).filter(
      // keyVal is the two-part Array of key and key-value:
      (keyVal) => {
        // we use a destructuring assignment to retrieve the
        // key and val elements from the keyVal Array:
        let [key, val] = keyVal;
        
        // we then use String.prototype.includes() to ascertain
        // whether the key includes the text provided in the
        // needle variable; String.prototype.includes() returns
        // a Boolean, true if the needle is included and false
        // if it is not included. Therefore we use this assessment
        // to determine whether we retain (if true) or discard (if
        // false) the current Array-element:
        return key.includes(needle);
      // we then use Array.prototype.map() to iterate over the
      // results of Array.filter():
      }).map(
        (arr) => {
          // we retrieve the name and count variables
          // from the current Array-element (an Array):
          let [name, count] = arr;
          // and return those items as an Object:
          return {
            // here we provide the property-name ('attribute'):
            attribute: name,
            // but use destructuring assignment to pass the
            // count both as the property-name and the
            // property-value:
            count,
          }
        });
  // we return filtered array to the calling context:
  return filteredAttributeCount;
}

console.log(attributeCount('data'));
/*

[
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-type",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-max-length",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-min-length",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-url",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-table",
    "count": 1
  }
]
*/
```

```html
<input type="date" data-input-type="date" />

<input type="email" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-type="email" />

<input type="text" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-url="report" data-input-table="sale" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/04gp7haL/1/).

The above approach works – or at least seems to, by my understanding of the problem in the question – but it's worth noting that a simple change might better serve your needs. In my own use-cases I typically find myself searching *within* an element, or elements, for something hence my use of:

```
let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(`${haystack} *`)],
```

This, of course, will create an Array of all elements found within the element matched by the `haystack` selector. You may, however, wish to simply search for specific elements matching a selector, for example `<input>` in this question. If that's the case then the above code could be easily adapted by removing the `*` from the `document.querySelectorAll()`:

```
let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(`${haystack}`)],
```

And then calling the function like so:

```
attributeCount('data', 'input');
```

```js
// using Arrow function syntax to declare a function, passing in a
// default-value for the 'haystack' argument;
// needle:   String, a value by which the collection of attributes
//           is filtered,
// haystack: String, a selector for the element to search within:
const attributeCount = (needle, haystack = 'body') => {

  // here we use document.querySelectorAll(), passing the
  // haystack selector into the function via a template-literal,
  // which allows variables to interpolated in place; the
  // iterable NodeList returned by document.querySelectorAll()
  // is converted to an Array using the Array-literal along with
  // the spread syntax; this allows us to use Array methods
  // on the Array of Nodes:
  let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(`${haystack}`)],
    // this is a collection of all Attributes present on all
    // elements returned previously, using Array.prototype.map():
    allAttributes = elements.map(
      // here we use an Arrow function to pass the current
      // element-node of the Array of element-nodes we're
      // iterating over into the function:
      (el) => {
        // here we convert the el.attributes NamedNodeMap
        // into an Array, again using the Array-literal and
        // spread syntax; we then iterate over those Attributes
        // using Array.prototype.map():
        let attrs = [...el.attributes].map(
          // another Arrow function, passing in the
          // current key-value Object to the function body:
          (keyVal) => {
            // we use a destructuring assignment to
            // retrieve the nodeName and the nodeValue
            // from the property-values of the same name
            // from the keyVal Object:
            let {
              nodeName,
              nodeValue
            } = keyVal;
            // here we return an Object comprised of the following
            // values:
            return {
              attributeName: nodeName,
              attributeValue: nodeValue
            }
          });
        // and here we return the following Object,
        // with the 'node' property of the Object being the
        // current element-node (in case that might be required
        // in a future context), and an Array of the attributes:
        return {
          'node': el,
          'attributes': attrs,
        }
      }
    ),
    
    // here we use Array.prototype.reduce() to reduce the Array
    // of element-nodes and their attributes to a different format:
    attributeCounts = allAttributes.reduce(
      (acc, curr) => {
        // we create an Array of all the attribute names held in the
        // current Object's attributes Array:
        let keys = curr.attributes.map((a) => a.attributeName);
        // we iterate over those attribute-names using
        // Array.prototype.forEach(), passing the 'key' variable
        // in via the Arrow function syntax:
        keys.forEach(
          (key) => {
            // if there is no key on the accumulator Object
            // matching the current attribute-name:
            if (!acc[key]) {
              // we initialise that Object-property and set
              // its value to 1:
              acc[key] = 1;
            } else {
              // otherwise, if that key does exist we increment
              // its count by one:
              acc[key]++;
            }
          });
          
        // we return the accumulator for the next iteration:  
        return acc;
      // here is the default accumulator initialised for the
      // function:
      }, {}),
    // to rerieve the filtered attribute contents, we use
    // Object.entries() to break down the attributeCounts
    // Object into a two-dimensional Array containing multiple
    // sub-arrays, each of which is a key-value pair of the
    // property-name and property-value of the attributeCounts
    // Object; we then use use Array.prototype.filter() to filter
    // that Array of key-value pairs:
    filteredAttributeCount = Object.entries(attributeCounts).filter(
      // keyVal is the two-part Array of key and key-value:
      (keyVal) => {
        // we use a destructuring assignment to retrieve the
        // key and val elements from the keyVal Array:
        let [key, val] = keyVal;
        
        // we then use String.prototype.includes() to ascertain
        // whether the key includes the text provided in the
        // needle variable; String.prototype.includes() returns
        // a Boolean, true if the needle is included and false
        // if it is not included. Therefore we use this assessment
        // to determine whether we retain (if true) or discard (if
        // false) the current Array-element:
        return key.includes(needle);
      // we then use Array.prototype.map() to iterate over the
      // results of Array.filter():
      }).map(
        (arr) => {
          // we retrieve the name and count variables
          // from the current Array-element (an Array):
          let [name, count] = arr;
          // and return those items as an Object:
          return {
            // here we provide the property-name ('attribute'):
            attribute: name,
            // but use destructuring assignment to pass the
            // count both as the property-name and the
            // property-value:
            count,
          }
        });
  // we return filtered array to the calling context:
  return filteredAttributeCount;
}

console.log(attributeCount('data', 'input'));
/*

[
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-type",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-max-length",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-min-length",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-url",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "attribute": "data-input-table",
    "count": 1
  }
]
*/
```

```html
<input type="date" data-input-type="date" />

<input type="email" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-type="email" />

<input type="text" data-input-max-length="60" data-input-min-length="8" data-input-url="report" data-input-table="sale" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/04gp7haL/2/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).
- [`NamedNodeMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap).
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
- [Template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).